# Configuring Spring + Hibernate JPA Transaction Manager through JTA

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa

I previously had this config for Hibernate using RESOURCE-LOCAL transaction type:

persistence.xml:

```
<persistence-unit name="myPU" transaction-type="JTA">
        <provider>org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider</provider>

</persistence-unit>
```

applicationContext (dataaccess bit):

```
<bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor" />

<bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager" p:entityManagerFactory-ref="entityManagerFactory"></bean>

<bean id="entityManagerFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
    <property name="jpaVendorAdapter" ref="jpaAdapter" />
    <property name="persistenceUnitName" value="myPU"/>
    <property name="jpaProperties">
        <props>
            <prop key="javax.persistence.validation.mode">none</prop>
        </props>
    </property>
</bean>

<bean id="entityManager" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.SharedEntityManagerBean">
    <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="entityManagerFactory" />
</bean>

<bean id="sessionFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaSessionFactoryBean">
    <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="entityManagerFactory" />
    <!-- Are there any other properties required? -->
</bean>

<bean id="jpaAdapter" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter">

    <property name="showSql" value="true" />
    <property name="generateDdl" value="false" />
</bean>

<bean id="dataSource" class="org.springframework.jndi.JndiObjectFactoryBean">
    <property name="jndiName" value="java:comp/env/jdbc/CNTXESDB" />
    <property name="lookupOnStartup" value="true" />
    <property name="cache" value="true" />
    <property name="proxyInterface" value="javax.sql.DataSource" />
</bean>
```

But this kind of transaction seems not to work with Glassfish, so I had to switch to JTA transactions.

The problem is -- to get Spring to manage transaction creation (through @Transactional) I need to define a `TransactionManager` bean but `JtaTransactionManager` included in spring-tx does not accept an entityManagerFactory bean, so it does not know where the entityManager is in order to open/close/flush Hibernate session.

So how can I configure Spring with Hibernate to use JTA transactions?

**EDIT:**
turns out you **can** use RESOURCE_LOCAL transactions with Glassfish, but somehow you cannot have a persistence.xml file. I renamed this file to `my_persistence.xml` and configured `LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean` like this:

```
<bean id="entityManagerFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
        <property name="jpaVendorAdapter" ref="jpaAdapter" />
        <property name="persistenceUnitName" value="myPU"/>
        <property name="persistenceXmlLocation" value="classpath:META-INF/my_persistence.xml" />
        <property name="jpaProperties">
            <props>
                <prop key="javax.persistence.validation.mode">none</prop>
            </props>
        </property>
    </bean>
```

Comment: I suggest to rename the bean `<bean id="entityManager"` could be a problem.. Anyway [follow this tutorial](http://softwarecave.org/2014/03/15/using-jpa-and-jta-with-spring/)

Comment: Obviously that will not work. You specified that you want to use JTA but in yuour configuration use local transactions. Either change your `persistence.xml` or configure JTA transactions correctly.

Comment: @M.Deinum what I am asking is just that: how to configure it properly

Comment: Why would you need JTA there is nothing preventing you from using local transactions on glassfish. That is the point I was trying to make, if it doesn't work with resource-local it is because your setup is wrong. If you don't need JTA then don't use JTA.

Comment: @M.Deinum I am getting this error using RESOURCE_LOCAL: `Only persistence units with transaction type JTA can be used as a container managed entity manager.`

Comment: Ah. Nice glassfish is trying to bootstrap JPA too. They are competing. Just remove `persistence.xml` you don't need it with Spring, or rename it and add the `persistenceXml` property to the `LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean` to specify the new name/location of the file. Easiest is to just remove it.

Comment: @M.Deinum is that to fix the problem of my question or to allow RESOURCE LOCAL in glassfish?

Comment: The latter, which fixes your problem. You don't need JTA and in this case you will run into other issues as now both Spring and GlassFish try to manage your `EntityManagerFactory` which is actually the underlying cause for the issue you have. Which in turn wouldn't even be fixed with adding JTA and would lead to other problems...

Comment: @kelmer were you able to resolve this issue?

Comment: @Rohit it did work using M.Deinum answer, although I do not exactly know the reason. My guess is that, having found a persistence.xml file, Glassfish tries to create the EntityManager itself and thus it is clashing with the one I create through a Spring bean. I have edited my answer to include the line that fixed it.

Comment: @M.Deinum can you confirm my guess please? I am curious :P

Comment: @Rohit That is what I said in one of my earlier comments.

Comment: @M.Deinum but I do need a persistence.xml file to configure the EntityManager, what do you mean "you don't need it with Spring"

Comment: When using Spring you don't need a `persistence.xml` that is what I meant nothing more nothing less.

Comment: Well that may be true, but if I remove the persistence.xml altogether my application stops working -- obviously I need to do something else to make it work.

Comment: @kelmar to avoid `persistence.xml` you need to use `packagetoscan` property(set it to base package of entity beans) in `entityManagerFactory` bean. remove `persistenceUnitName` and `persistenceXmlLocation` properties.

Comment: Also I would suggest reading [this](http://piotrnowicki.com/2012/11/types-of-entitymanagers-application-managed-entitymanager/) and [this](http://www.baeldung.com/2011/12/13/the-persistence-layer-with-spring-3-1-and-jpa/)

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar problem and finally I solved as you can see in this little demo:
https://github.com/miguelangelprogramacion/spring4_jpa_hibernate

With [1] as a reference, I prefer to use Spring's Transaction Support before JTA.

Also, I've used an annotation based approach.

[1] http://spring.io/blog/2011/08/15/configuring-spring-and-jta-without-full-java-ee/